# Can Google DFP email out reports with CSV attachments from pre-defined templates?

Tags: advertising, usability, google-dfp, banners, openx

We have recently changed our advertising setup from OpenX over to Google DFP.

One of the biggest headaches is setting up the automated reports with CSV attachments for our clients. There are **TOO MANY** steps involved in DFP to do such a simple task.

In DFP, you have to invite an email address, wait for them to allow DFP to access (they have to sign up for a Google Account if they don't have one), manually setup the views for the CSV with the date range, save and export adding the client's email address ***again***, set the date range ***again*** for the delivery.

It's frustrating to do this each time going through repeated steps and DFP doesn't seem to have any templates/preset rules for automated stats delivery.

While in OpenX, all you had to do was tick a checkbox for "**Email campaign delivery reports**" on the client's setup page, put in a number for the delivery reports and the software does the rest:

[image]

**Did somebody at Google drop the ball on the ease of use of DFP or am I missing something?**

Comment: Yes, somebody dropped the ball on ease of use at DFP.   I've never tried to set up emailed CSV reports there, but I find the entire interface to be overly complex.  DFP does have an [API](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-publishers/) that you might be able to use to send these reports yourself.